# Attribute error in python unittest

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

On executing this unittest getting

AttributeError: 'BaseUnit' object has no attribute 'driver'

```
import unittest
import redis
from selenium import webdriver
redis = redis.Redis(host='abc', port='123')
keys = redis.keys('*')
raw_baseunit = redis.get('test:baseunit')`enter code here`

class BaseUnit(unittest.TestCase):
        def setup(self):
                self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

        def test(self):
                self.driver.get("myurl")
                self.driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys("ngeo_pur1")
                self.driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys("anything")
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/section/div/form/ul/li[5]/div[2]/div/input').click()
                self.driver.get("url")
                self.driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("18757424").click()
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tabs']/nav/ul/li[2]/a/i").click()
                Actual = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='subcat_baseModelSection.baseModelChoice']/div/div[1]").text

                keys = redis.keys('*')
                raw_baseunit = redis.get('test:baseUnit')
                print "Actual Base Unit=",Actual
                print "Expected Base Unit=",raw_baseunit
                self.assetEquals(raw_baseunit,Actual)

        def teardown(self):
                self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Tried changing the class name 'BaseUnit' as well

Comment: Could you add the full traceback? it would help to solve the issue

Comment: @ lapinkoira
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unittest_base_unit.py", line 13, in test
    self.driver.get("link")
AttributeError: 'BaseUnit' object has no attribute 'driver'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

Comment: first try to print self.driver object, and see what it gives?

Comment: Your setup function isn't correct? It should be `setUp` https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp

Comment: This is a typo question and should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying the setup class's name to this. I just read the doc and the setup class is written with the U in uppercase

```
def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

Comment: Changing the class name to def setUp(self):  solved the issue.
Thanks @http://stackoverflow.com/users/3767778/lapinkoira

Comment: You welcome. Check the rest of the method's name in the doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp and mark this answer as accepted if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

The methods you want to override in [`unittest.TestCase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) are `setUp` and `tearDown` (note the capital "U" and "D"), not `setup` and `teardown`.

Your all-lowercase `setup` method doesn't get called before the test methods run (if it gets called at all), so the `self.driver` attribute doesn't exist when then `test` method tries to use it.